# What happens when i write find_by(integer)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I once accidentially wrote a line of code as:

> User.find_by(params[:id])

What i meant is

> User.find_by(id: params[:id])

But the code didn't throw an exception, it ran ok and always returned the last user in the database, which drove me crazy finding where i did wrong.
So what happens if we pass an integer into find_by? why does it return the last object?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: i already checked the API doc. But i couldn't realy answer the question. From reading the doc for "find_by" i suppose that returning the "last" object is just coincident because order doesn't matter. Please correct me if i'm wrong. And how an integer is considered "matching the specified conditions" here? Sorry if the question is dumb. I'm noob and have just finished Hartl's tutorial after 2 weeks of reading! Thanks!

Comment: find_by expects expression in the bracket that evaluates into boolean. But if you place find_by(true) or find_by(false) you will get the first entry in the table, not the last... Are you running some kind of "railzoid", if any such thing exists?

Comment: Facepalm! I should be fishslapped badly!! i forgot that users are sorted by created_at so the last added one will appear first!

Comment: BTW what is "railszoid" if you don't mind? Google seems to show that it's a person's nickname??

Comment: It's a custom expression. Something that should work like rails but it does not... Rails-oid=Railzoid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the api docs, `find_by` is just sugar for

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

`params[:id]` is actually a string, so you end up doing `where("456")` which ends up as a fragment of sql like `WHERE (456)`. Unless you pass 0, databases seem to interpret this as matching all rows.